# Setting up Console.WriteLine & Debug.WriteLine

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clr

When I create a Console Application in Visual Studio, a `cmd` Window is automatically provided  on which text can be written to and read from. Where is this behaviour set up? Does *VS* do it or is it merely a consequence of a compiled *.Net* program?

On a side note, how does *VS* hook `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is magic");` up to the *output* Window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console behaviour is part of the PE header in the exe; there is a flag to distinguish between console and windows apps. The value of this flag is pretty much the only fundamental difference between a windows exe and a console exe (you can still create forms from a console exe, etc - and you can write to the console from a windows exe, although you won't be able to see anything).

You can toggle this flag using `editbin` if you want to play with it - the `/subsystem:windows` flag, in particular.

The debug output is because the debugger attaches to pre-defined trace points to gather the output. If you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> it runs *without* attaching any of these hooks, so you get something closer to running it directly from the shell.

Comment: Can this flag be set in *VS* or is this in the compiled *exe*?

Comment: @aligray - the flag is in the generated exe. You choose it in VS by choosing between windows exe and console exe.

Comment: If you want to see console output from a windows exe, then use P/Invoke to call `[AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: You can change the Output Type setting to get a console window in a Winforms app (Project + Properties, Application tab).  Console.Write() output is redirected to the IDE's Output window by the Visual Studio Hosting Process (Project + Properties, Debug tab).

Answer (score 0):

when your console application is compiled, it creates an .exe file which is a console application. cmd window is invoked if you start that exe, say from windows explorer. If you run that app without debugger, it's essentially the same thing as if you ran it from Run command or windows explorer...